# How can CMD be opened at locked screen?

Tags: cmd.exe, password-recovery, lock-screen, bypass

So my computer had a no signal black screen for almost 8-9 maybe 13 years finally got the black screen off and turns out my aunt who I let use my pc put a  password on my admin account.
So I've looked up all the ways to  bring up the CMD on lock screen and no matter how I follow the steps perfectly.
In system 32 I can not find the sethc  and all my files has DII behind them.
I see no sethc.exe or anything close to it.
I'm so lost and I don't wanna clean my PC because I'll have to redownload my Vista and anything else.
That might be vital to my gaming.
So any help will be a big help

Comment: **Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will allow you to use CMD when not logged in (lock screen, logon screen, etc.)

1. If the PC's BIOS is password protected, crack it using https://bios-pw.org/
2. Burn Ubuntu to a CD or USB. You will need administrative rights to burn the ISO to a USB flash drive; you will not for a CD.
3. Boot the computer you need to crack (to Ubuntu, not Windows). Select "Try Ubuntu" so it doesn't install when booting
4. Open the Ubuntu file manager and navigate to the Windows disk.
5. Browse to `C:\Windows\system32`
6. Rename `cmd.exe` to `cmdreal.exe`
7. Rename `utilman.exe` to `cmd.exe`
8. Rename `cmdreal.exe` to `utilman.exe`
9. Reboot into Windows.
10. Click the Ease of Access menu in the lower-left hand corner of the logon screen
11. Type `net user account password` where account is the username of the account you want to reset the password for and password is the new password
12. You should be in. You can either run `sfc /scannow` in CMD to automatically undo the file changes you made or you can boot back into Ubuntu and rename them.

Comment: Ty vary helpful I hope I gave you a thumbs up not down.